# select and apply event to dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply some css using jquery to for example `$('#btn').('color','red');`

but the problem is that is not working for my next new added element, #btn. It work only to my existed element.

I use

```
$('#btn').on(function(){
   $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

but no luck

Comment: you cannot do it like it... any dom manipulation have to be done once the element is created... delegation using `on` is specific to event handling ... it cannot be used for dom manipulation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: You really should **[research](https://www.google.com.lb/search?q=bind+on+dynamic+element&oq=bind+on+dynamic+element&aqs=chrome..69i57.4424j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)** before asking a question.

Comment: Just to clarify - because it sounds like you are using `#btn` more than once - **ID's should be unique!** Expected behaviour should be that `$('#btn')` selects a single element - the first it encounters.  Perhaps try selecting by class name: `$('.myBtn')`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use .livequery() plugin

e.g.

```
$('#btn').livequery(function() {
  $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

Hope that helps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [DOM4 Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) ([W3C Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#mutation-observers)). They can be used to get notified if the DOM is changed, so you can work on the newly inserted nodes for example. Also check out the [Mutation Summary library](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/). However, [not all browsers do support this feature yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver).

If this seems overkill for your use case, try setting the CSS before inserting anything or firing a custom event after insertion (e.g. using [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)).